# Como desabilitar todas as opções para desligar o Windows até certo horário? (hardening)

Tags: windows

> Usando **regedit** e **ferramentas de sistemas**. Parâmetros a serem bloqueados: Caso: imagine que você está configurando um pc / notebook para um usuário da empresa da qual é gerente de rede e TI. Seu trabalho é aplicar as políticas de segurança e regras da empresa a todos os equipamentos da empresa. Para isso, é necessário entender e aplicar algumas regras, tais como: O funcionário não poderá desligar o computador quando quiser, apenas às 18h. Portanto, você precisará remover todos os comandos de desligamento do PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abra o `regedit` **(Window+R)** e percorra o caminho:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideShutDown
```

Abra a chave `"value"` e altere o seu valor para `1`.

Sua opção Desligar foi removida para todos, mas todas as outras opções ainda estão lá. Isso inclui a tela de login e `alt+ctrl+del` tela.

Altere para 0 para trazê-lo de volta.

Isso apenas remove as opções do menu e não evita o desligamento de usuários com a política de emitir o comando de desligamento por meio de um comando ou programa separado.

Para remover de um perfil já configurado, altere as chaves associadas em:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\current\device\Start
```

É interessante manter um perfil de usuário para o funcionário e assim ficará mais fácil realizar os bloqueios que deseja sem atrapalhar o registro geral.

Isso não impede que os usuários:

executando outros programas que executam essas funções. Por exemplo, no prompt de comando, eles podem executar: `"shutdown /s"` para desligar o computador ou `"shutdown /r"` para reiniciar o computador.

e também não impede que usuários faça `logoff` do Windows e desligue ou reinicie o computador puxando o cabo de força, desconectando a fonte ou puxando o pino da tomada.

**Dica para o Windows 10:**

Existe o Editor de Políticade Grupo, mas o Editor de Política de Grupo está disponível apenas nas edições Pro, Enterprise e Education do Windows 10, e não no Windows 10 Home.

Mais informações são fornecidas nestas páginas:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-shutdown-power-button-login-start-menu
https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/prevent-shutdown-of-windows/

Tratando-se de `"Group Policy Editor"` **(Win+R e gpedit.msc)**, você poderá adicionar/remover grupos específicos de usuários para permitir/impedir que desliguem o sistema.

(Win+R e gpedit.msc)

```
Configuração do computador-> Configurações do Windows-> Configurações de segurança-> Políticas locais-> Atribuição de direitos do usuário-> Desligar o sistema
```

Espero ter ajudado.